# Not found error when running external tools Android Studio

Tags: android, linux, android-studio

I have a `run.sh` like this

```
virtualenv -p python3 env
source env/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python3 -m profilo.workflow_demo trace.log blocks
```

When i run this on terminal it runs ok but when i run this shell in external tools android studio it raise an error.

```
/home/cpu10475-local/Desktop/python/run.sh: 2: /home/cpu10475-local/Desktop/python/run.sh: source: not found
/home/cpu10475-local/Desktop/python/run.sh: 3: /home/cpu10475-local/Desktop/python/run.sh: pip3: not found
Process finished with exit code 1
```

My tool config is here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXsSI.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the External Tools in Android Studio doesn't support `source`. So you should try removing the first 2 lines and installing `pip3` then run the module again.